# Checking if a math function is valid

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am given the function {1,2,3,4,5}. I have to receive user input on how many ordered pairs he wants, then verify if the function is valid (values for the x-coordinate have to be between 1 and 5, and an x-coordinate CAN'T be repeated). I know how to loop for and check if the value of X is between 1 and 5, however, I am having trouble checking the string for repeating elements. I wrote the conditional expression for x less than 1 and bigger than 5, but I am stumped on how to write an expression that checks for repeating elements. Can somebody help me with that please? This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Functions
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int []domain = new int [5];
        int [] range = new int [5];
        int orderedPairs = 0;

        System.out.println ("Enter the number of ordered pairs please: ");
        orderedPairs = in.nextInt();
        while (orderedPairs < 0 || orderedPairs > 5)
        {
            System.out.println ("This input is invalid. Enter a number between 0 and 5 and try   again:");
            orderedPairs = in.nextInt ();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedPairs; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter the x-coordinate please: ");
            domain [i][0] = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println ("Enter the y-coordinate please: ");
            range [i][0] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedPairs; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("f(" + domain [i][0] + "): " + range [i][0]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedPairs;i++)
        {
            if (domain [i][0] > 5 || domain [i][0] < 1)
            {
                function = false;
            }

            for (int n = i + 1; n < orderedPairs; n++)
            {
                if (domain[i] == domain [n] && range [n] != range [i])
                {
                    function = false;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Edit : 
That is all it took, apparently! :)

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is this:

1) Loop over all the domains.

2) For each domain, retrieve its value. Then loop over the domains counting the number of domains whose value equals the retrieved value.

3) If that value is anything other than 1 for each domain, report an error.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome, I appreciate the help! I figured out how to do it now :)